# how to make other forms goes over my form

Tags: wpf, xaml, borderless

i have a borderless form and when i try to drag other forms over it they will just go under it and not over it why does it do that?

```
 WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseDown="Window_MouseDown" Topmost="True" x:Name="win" WindowStyle="None" Height="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}"  Width="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" AllowsTransparency="True" Visibility="Visible" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" IsHitTestVisible="True" Loaded="win_Loaded">
<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <WindowChrome 
    CaptionHeight="0"
    ResizeBorderThickness="5" />
</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `Topmost="True"`. Just remove that.